# Backbone 'this' is being set to 'window'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, this

I'm trying to create a Backbone View object. In my initialize code I'm setting a var self = this. And I'm getting a 'self.set is not a function' error. This is because, looking at the debugger, this refers to 'window' when I'm declaring the var self. I have not seen this before.

Can anyone tell why the window is being selected for 'this'

code:

```
var SongObjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
defaults:{
    el:'#playList',
    template:''
},
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    self.set({
        el:'#playList'
    });
    alert('initializing songObjectView template');
    self.template = _.template($('#songObjectView').html());
    self.render();
},
render:function(){
    $(this.el).append(this.template);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `set` method in a `View` object, maybe you wanted [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement)?

If you happen to find `this` being the `window` object, it is likely because you've lost context. And there's no reason for `self` variable assignment, as others pointed out. You can use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) and other ways to pass and set context.

I tried to clean your example, I hope this helps:

```js
var SongModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    artist: '',
    title: ''
  }
});

var SongView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('Title: <%=title%><br>by <em><%=artist%></em>'),
  initialize:function(){
    this.render();
  },
  render:function(){
    this.$el.append( this.template(this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
  }
});

var song = new SongModel({
  title: "A Hard Day's Night",
  artist: "The Beatles"
});

var songView = new SongView({ el: '#playlist', model: song });
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
<div id="playlist"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my issue already... Syntax. I'm new to Backbone and here's what I changed that fixed the issue. I'm open to critique as to why this is correct.

working code:

```
var SongObjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
template:'',
el:'#playList',
initialize:function(){
    var self = this;
    alert('initializing songObjectView template');
    self.template = _.template($('#songObjectView').html());
    self.render();
},
render:function(){
    $(this.el).append(this.template);
}
});
```

Comment: `var self = this; ` doesn't make any sense to me. It will work without it. Just call all functions on `this` marker